# Trying to change many chars in an active workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I´m trying to write a code that change the properties of many charts in a workbook that is active. All my sheets in this workbook have charts.

```
Sub ChangeGraphType()
    Dim cht As ChartType
    For Each cht In ActiveWorkbook.Charts
        cht.Type = xlArea   'change columns to area type
    Next cht
End Sub
```

But when I run it, my graphs don´t change. Please, where is my mistake? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhh, I think the solution could be two loops: one for the charts and the other for the sheets. I tried the code below and it worked.

```
Sub ChangeGraphType()
    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim cht As ChartObject

    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
            cht.Activate
            cht.Chart.Type = xlArea
        Next cht
    Next sht
End Sub
```

I don´t know if there is another way without using loop, but I guess it makes more sense now.